# How to sum values when zipping similar key to build a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have `A = [a, b, c, d, a, d, c]` and `B=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Why `dict(zip(A,B))` doesn't return `{'a': 6, 'b': 2, 'c': 10, 'd': 10}` ?

How to make it works?

Comment: ...python can't read your mind; how is it supposed to know that you want to *add* those values and not, I don't know, multiply them?

Comment: How is `'a': 6`?

Comment: @DirtyBit I want to add every values when a key occurs multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple iteration

**Ex:**

```
A = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "d", "c"] 
B= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

result = {}
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    if a not in result:
        result[a] = 0
    result[a] += b
print(result)
```

---

Or using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(int)
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    result[a] += b
pprint(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 6, 'b': 2, 'c': 10, 'd': 10}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

`dict` will just over-write the values.. what you want won't come so easily. You'd need something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import defaultdict

A = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "d", "c"]
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

output = defaultdict(int)

for a,b in zip(A,B):
        output[a] += b

print(output)
```

The result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 6, 'b': 2, 'c': 10, 'd': 10})
```

`defaultdict` will set each new keys value to `0` by default.. allowing us to call `+=` on each key without error.. giving us the sum we need.